# Align center a button at mobile devices - Email Template

Tags: email-template, content-builder, responsive-design

I'm trying to align center a button on mobile devices but with no success.
Below you can see my code.

[image]

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td align="left">
         <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
               <td class="innertd buttonblock" bgcolor="#F7E514" style=" border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #F7E514;"><a target="_blank" class="buttonstyles" style=" font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #353535; text-decoration: none; display: block; text-align: left; background-color: #F7E514; border: 0px solid #009DDC; padding: 15px 50px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;" href="http://" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://">button 1</a></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Can somebody please give me some ideas?

Thank you in advance

---

Thank you for the promt response.
I am using 2 columns at the desktop version (see the image below).The button is left aligned and I want to align center to the mobile version

[image]

Comment: Hi @andreas Kodelai. instead of screenshot can you please place your HTML code in your original question?

Comment: initial code reformatting would also be great before putting it here. Also - how does this look like on layout exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering the button in a single column layout then the below code will work:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td align="center">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
               <td bgcolor="#F7E514" class="innertd buttonblock" style=" border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #F7E514;">
                  <a alias="" class="buttonstyles" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="http://" style=" font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #353535; text-decoration: none; display: block; text-align: left; background-color: #F7E514; border: 0px solid #009DDC; padding: 15px 50px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;" target="_blank" title="">button 1</a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**: Since you are using layout as 2 column the below code for button will work:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td align="center">
         <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
               <td class="innertd buttonblock" bgcolor="#361D6D" style=" border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #361D6D;"><a target="_blank" class="buttonstyles" style=" font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; line-height: 100%; background-color: #361D6D; border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 25px; border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px;" href="http://" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://">Button Text</a></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the screenshot:

**For Desktop:**

[image]

**For Mobile :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a table. Use div elements. That way things will float dynamically and it will be responsive to multiple layouts.